# Show create table tablename in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MySQL it is possible to do `show create table tablename`

What is the SQL Server equivalent?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In SSMS, right-click on the table node and "Script Table As" / "Create".

There is no built in 'script this table' T-SQL.

sp_help 'tablename' gives useful table information if that'd do.

Comment: Thanks for the `sp_help` tip. I have so many tables that SSMS won't display them (yes, appalling db design), and this was the solution.

Answer (score 12):

One that might be close:

```
exec sp_columns YourTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

if multiple database and schema exists in SQL_Dataserver,
Then you need to provide the exact table location with sp_help within single quotes.

```
exec sp_help 'database_name.schema_name.table_name'
```