# Create class name in Rails for existing table name present in SQL server

Tags: ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to use SQL server table in rails.
Suppose I already have one table T_SDF in SQL server and I want to fetch all data from this table.

How can I create a model or class in Rails?

I am using Rails version 3.2.9 and Ruby version 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `self.table_name =`
Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name%3D

Example:

```
class SomeModel
  self.table_name = 'T_SDF'
end
```

### Update

To generate a model for an existing table.

Run `rails g model t_sdf`. We don't want to pass any parameters to this since the table already exists.

#### Preparing the Migration

The previous command should have generated a file such as: `db/migrate/20150415071801_create_t_sdfs.rb`.

We will want to update it to create the table exactly as it already exists.
In MySQL I tend to execute the command `show create table {{table_name}}`
In SQL Server you should be able to follow the instructions here: [show create table tablename (how do i do this in sql server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526982/show-create-table-tablename-how-do-i-do-this-in-sql-server)

Once you have the string to create the table, paste the string into the execute statement in the example below.

```
class CreateTSdfs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # We wrap the command in an unless statement because we
    # don't want to run it on production. However, it is important for
    # the table to be created for developers working on local databases.
    unless table_exists?('T_SDF')
      execute "paste the create table sql statement here"
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_table 'T_SDF'
  end
end
```

#### Preparing the Model

You should just need to set the table name of model file.
`app/models/t_sdf.rb`

```
class TSdf
  self.table_name = 'T_SDF'
end
```

Comment: Hi jkarayusuf ,what i want,Suppose table T_SDF is already is present in SQL server.I have to access all the values present in that table.How should the model created like "rails g model .......".

Comment: Can i access the field values by creating object for This TSdf class ?

Comment: Yes. Image the T_SDF table has a the field `name` which is a `varchar(255)`.
You could then access the data by executing: `TSdf.find(id).name`

Comment: Rails will generate a method on the TSdf class for each column in the table.