# Generate create table SQL script for all tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create the SQL code that in its output will return the CREATE TABLE SQL for all tables in current database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there an analog of MySQL's "SHOW CREATE TABLE" that you can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create SQL script that create database and tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771047/create-sql-script-that-create-database-and-tables)

Comment: Hmmm - seems not -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526982/show-create-table-tablename-how-do-i-do-this-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 35):

In `SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)`

Right click on the DB_NAME -> Select Task -> Select Generate Script.

Follow along the presented wizard and select all tables in that database to generate the scripts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question.  They were looking for a SQL script to perform this action.

Comment: @DaleK See my comment on your answer.  Any others that come looking, the answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Answer (score 0):

Use a Visual Studio SQL Server Database Project as follows:

1. Create a Visual Studio SQL Server Database Project.

[image]

2. From the Project Menu, select Import > Database ...
3. Right click on the project and click publish.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I really love the ability to create database projects from existing databases. You can even track changes between your prod/dev DBs. Totally underrated answer!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question.  They were looking for a SQL script to perform this action.

Comment: @DaleK I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP wanted a SQL script that would generate the create scripts.  Anyone could use SSMS or Visual Studio, but that doesn't satisfy unattended scripting needs.  The correct answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Comment: @DaleK Are you serious??  "I need to create the SQL code that in it's output will return the CREATE TABLE SQL for all tables in current database."  What part of that don't you understand?  He needed a SQL script.  That's not my opinion; that was the request.