# Excel VBA - writing Data from SQL/Recordset very slow

Tags: sql, excel, recordset

I am trying to write SQL Server data to an Excel sheet but it is very slow. Is there something to optimize? Approximately, 4000 entries at 20 cColumns takes 6-7 minutes.

Database ("freigabe") Module: Connecting to Database and get RecordSet
(this works like a charm)

```vb
Private Function ConnectSQL() As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};" _
            & "SERVER=xxxxx;" _
            & " DATABASE=xxxxx;" _
            & "UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxx; OPTION=3"

        conn.Open

    Set ConnectSQL = conn
End Function

Public Function load(Optional ByVal FieldName As String = "", Optional ByVal fieldValue As String = "", Optional ByVal ComparisonOperator As String = "=")
'wenn fehler return?
'-> Über errorhandler retun rs oder boolen
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim contition As String

    contition = " "

    Dim sqlfrom As String
    Dim sqlto As String


On Error GoTo Fehler:


    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & TBLNAME & " WHERE storno='0' AND created BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-15'"

    Set conn = ConnectSQL()
        rs.Open sql, conn, adOpenStatic
    Set load = rs

    Exit Function
    End If
Fehler:
    load = Err.Description
End Function
```

Get/Write: Build a connection and retrieving recordset. The `While` loop is taking long. I am skipping text-rich columns (it gets faster but still too long). Showing a load-window so the person doesn't think that Excel "isn't working". After that, the data get's validated (not included).

```vb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim startt As Double
    Dim endt As Double

    Dim rngDst As Range

    Set rs = freigabe.load()


    Set rngDst = Worksheets("Freigaben").Range("G2")

    With Worksheets("Freigaben").Range("g2:Z50000")
        .ClearContents
        '.CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    Count = rs.RecordCount
    k = 0


    gui_laden.Show

    startt = Timer
    With rs
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
            While Not .EOF
                For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                    If i <> 13 And i <> 2 And i <> 10 And i <> 5 And i <> 6 And i <> 0 Then  rngDst.Offset(, i) = .Fields(i).Value 'skip unneccessary data and write
                Next i
                k = k + 1
                Debug.Print k & "/" & Count
                gui_laden.lbl_status = "Lade Daten herunter: " & k & "/" & Count
                gui_laden.Repaint
                .MoveNext
                DoEvents 'Ensure Application doesn't freeze
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
            Wend
        End If
    End With

    endt = Timer - startt
    Debug.Print "Dauer: " & endt
```

What I tried:

1. `CopyFromRecordSet` -> Application freezes
2. Test in new workbook -> same

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show the [column types for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526982/show-create-table-tablename-how-do-i-do-this-in-sql-server). You might have `varchar(max)`, `blob`, `double` with high precision.

Comment: For comparison, I can write 10,000 rows by 20 columns of random 250 characters to a plain workbook in about 6 secs. The workbook created was 35Mb. There must be something special about your workbook (formats ?) or is it on a network drive.

Comment: @Parfait I have integers, varchar(255) and one varchar max...

Comment: @CDP1802 I thought it may be the VPN tunnel (home office since last week) - but I get the record set very quick and so I thought it must be my loop? Or is it because of the tunnel? Thanks!

Comment: @Limesoft Replace the * with 1 field name in the SELECT and see what the time is. It would be better to define just the fields you want rather than using * in the SELECT.

Comment: Varchar max will be a problem if it exceeds Excel's cell limits of 32,767 characters. Omit columns and test. Always avoid `SELECT *` for maintainability and readability of code.

Comment: Wow! Works! Thanks, CDP1802 and Parfait ! Glad it was this small problem :)