# How do I select / identify a row based on criteria in a different row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've never posted on here before but, I am really stumped on this and looking for any assistance I get! I am not the best SQL code writer and I do not understand every concept but I am quick learner. So, I am not sure this is best way to accomplish my goal and if there is a more efficient way to complete this, I would be open to learning. I appreciate any help that can be provided.

### Task:

I am attempting to write a SQL code that will help me place a number under the "**Grab**" column that allows me to exclude other rows out that are not needed.

### Issue:

Pricing has a timeframe when it is applicable. The **[PriceBookTable]** captures the time frame range for each price book that is listed. However, as time goes on, some price books become outdated and do not need to be reviewed.

***Based on today's date, I am trying to identify the previous version price book as well as the next version (if there is one).***

### Table Used: [PriceBookTable]

| ID | Description | CategoryID | ParentID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **412** | 56 MSRP | **56** | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 413 | 3 MSRP | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 414 | 61 MSRP | 61 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 415 | 63 MSRP | 63 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 419 | 58 MSRP | 58 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 420 | 62 MSRP | 62 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 430 | 67 MSRP | 67 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 431 | 68 MSRP | 68 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 505 | 2020 Version 1 | **56** | **412** | 2020-08-31 | 2020-12-31 |
| 537 | 2021 Version 1 | **56** | **412** | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 586 | 2021 Version 2 | **56** | **412** | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-13 |
| 622 | 2021 Version 3 | **56** | **412** | 2021-04-14 | 2021-07-31 |
| 688 | 2021 Version 4 | **56** | **412** | 2021-08-01 | 2021-12-31 |

### Current Code:

```
USE [Database]

DECLARE @PriceBookID AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @PriceBookID = '412' --Parent Price Book ID

SELECT  A.*,
        [Grab] = CASE   WHEN A.ParentID IS NULL AND A.StartDate IS NULL AND A.EndDate IS NULL THEN 1 -- Always needs to be #1
                        WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate THEN 3 --Currently Active Price Book based on Today's Date
                        ELSE NULL END
FROM(   SELECT  ID,
                ParentID,
                [PriceBookDescription] = Description,
                StartDate,
                EndDate,
                [ActivePriceBook] = CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate THEN 'Active' ELSE NULL END,
                [PBOrder] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)
        FROM [PriceBookTable]
        WHERE 1=1 AND ID IN (@PriceBookID) OR ParentID IN (@PriceBookID)) A
```

### Current Output:

| ID | ParentID | PriceBookDescription | StartDate | EndDate | ActivePriceBook | PBOrder | Grab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 412 | Null | MSRP | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | **1** |
| 505 | 412 | 2020 Version 1 | 2020-08-31 | 2020-12-31 | NULL | 2 | NULL |
| 537 | 412 | 2021 Version 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | NULL | 3 | NULL |
| 586 | 412 | 2021 Version 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-13 | NULL | 4 | NULL |
| 622 | 412 | 2021 Version 3 | 2021-04-14 | 2021-07-31 | Active | 5 | **3** |
| 688 | 412 | 2021 Version 4 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-12-31 | NULL | 6 | NULL |

### Notes:

I originally was hoping that the "PBOrder" column would be useful for me but, as time goes on the list becomes bigger as more price books are created and, for example, row #4 [ID 586] will not always be relevant.

I would have just placed a "*WHERE ID IN ('412','586','622','688')*" statement but the ID's change based on different categories (not shown). So, I am stuck to the date range.

### Desired Output:

| ID | ParentID | PriceBookDescription | StartDate | EndDate | ActivePriceBook | PBOrder | Grab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 412 | Null | MSRP | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | **1** |
| 586 | 412 | 2021 Version 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-13 | NULL | 4 | **2** |
| 622 | 412 | 2021 Version 3 | 2021-04-14 | 2021-07-31 | Active | 5 | **3** |
| 688 | 412 | 2021 Version 4 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-12-31 | NULL | 6 | **4** |

I hope this makes sense and please let me know if you have any questions regarding this.

Thank you again for any help!

Comment: Some people on here will complain that you need to show the structure of how your tables are created, so please update/edit your question and show [how your table is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526982/show-create-table-tablename-in-sql-server). Thanks.

Comment: I don't really get the logic behind this `Grab` column, what is it supposed to represent? `Based on today's date, I am trying to identify the previous version price book as well as the next version (if there is one).` How is that connected to this `Grab` column in your expected output? It sounds like the `Grab` column is actually irrelevant, and really you are just trying to find the previous valid row and/or the next, but I'm unsure exactly what you want. By the way: `ID IN (@PriceBookID)` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Please enter the original data

Comment: @Martin thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will work on getting more information in this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface I guess it could be irrelevant. I'm more so using it as a visual confirmation what I am trying to achieve here. This statement is accurate to what my goal is: *"and really you are just trying to find the previous valid row and/or the next"*. However, I am bit lost how to get there with this dataset. Also, regarding *"ID IN (@PriceBookID) probably doesn't do what you think it does."* Is there a more appropriate way to use that?

Comment: Looks like the answer by @pwilcox was basically what I was getting at. If `@PriceBookID` is a comma separated list, then `ID IN (@PriceBookID)` will not work, it is the same as saying `ID = @PriceBookID` which obviously won't be true (and will cause conversion errors if `ID` is an `int`). What you need is either to split it `ID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PriceBookID, ','))` or much better: use a single-column Table Valued Parameter or table variable `ID IN (SELECT value FROM @PriceBookID)`

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah I guess I never thought about it like that. I am not entirely sure what "STRING_SPLIT" does and I will need to look into that a bit as well. I really appreciate your time in reviewing this code with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me awhile to understand what you wanted, but after figuring it out I was able to address what you need.  Basically, you want:

- To identify a single active record within a category based on the current date.
- Then get the adjacent inactive records, with respect to time, that share a parent record.
- Then get the record for the parent category and include it in the result set.
- The 'pbOrder' and 'grab' columns seem to be throughputs to achieve this goal.  You don't need them in the output.

If this is all correct, then you can delegate your identification of an active record to a `cross apply` calculation, and then use `lead` and `lag` in addition to the raw result to identify the active record as well as the adjacent ones in time.

```
declare @PriceBookID int = 412; -- why varchar, I would use int

with rowsToGrab as (

    select      pbt.*,
                ap.activePriceBook,
                grab = 
                    case 
                    when pbt.ParentID is null then 1
                    when lead(ap.ActivePriceBook) over(order by pbt.startDate) is not null then 1
                    when lag(ap.ActivePriceBook) over(order by pbt.startDate) is not null then 1
                    when ap.ActivePriceBook is not null then 1
                    end
    from        @PriceBookTable pbt
    cross apply (select ActivePriceBook = 
                    case 
                    when cast(getdate() as date) between startdate and enddate then 'Active' 
                    end
                ) ap
    where       @PriceBookID in (ID, ParentID)

)

select      id, ParentID, description as PriceBookDescription, StartDate, EndDate, ActivePriceBook
from        rowsToGrab
where       grab is not null
order by    id, StartDate
```

This produces:

| id | ParentID | PriceBookDescription | StartDate | EndDate | ActivePriceBook |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 412 |  | 56 MSRP |  |  |  |
| 586 | 412 | 2021 Version 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-13 |  |
| 622 | 412 | 2021 Version 3 | 2021-04-14 | 2021-07-31 | Active |
| 688 | 412 | 2021 Version 4 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-12-31 |  |

Comment: Hey @pwilcox, I apologize for not being more clear in my description and will work on that going forward with other future questions. This is what I was looking for and I will have to do some research on what exactly is a "Lead", "Lag" and "Cross Apply" in SQL since I have no idea how those work. Thank you very much for you help!