# Picking latest completing process timestamp per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I need help in picking latest completing process between 2 processes per day using SQL Server query as any one of the 2 processes can complete earlier for a given day. We need to pick the process based on MAX RunDateAndTime for a particular day. Not sure how to use ROW_NUMBER over partition by function in SQL Server. Below is the query what I prepared:

```
SELECT 
sj.name JobName
, ISNULL(sjs.step_name, 'Job Status') StepName
, dbo.agent_datetime(sjh.run_date, sjh.run_time) RunDateAndTime
, CASE sjh.run_status
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
  END RunStatus
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON sjh.job_id = sjs.job_id AND sjh.step_id = sjs.step_id  
WHERE (sj.name = 'Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2' AND sjh.step_id = 11) OR 
(sj.name = 'Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing' AND sjh.step_id = 6)
order by RunDateAndTime desc;
```

Output I am getting:

```
JobName                               StepName                 RunDateAndTime      RunStatus
Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-09 07:20:20.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-09 07:08:27.000 Succeeded

Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-08 04:43:53.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-08 04:47:18.000 Succeeded

Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-07 03:20:53.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-07 05:40:18.000 Succeeded

Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-06 14:24:33.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-06 13:10:18.000 Succeeded
```

Output I want:

```
JobName                               StepName                 RunDateAndTime      RunStatus
Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-09 07:20:20.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-08 04:47:18.000 Succeeded
Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing  Agent Only Tab Calculate    2023-08-07 05:40:18.000 Succeeded
Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2    COE_Daily_Export_BIW    2023-08-06 14:24:33.000 Succeeded
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL?

Comment: You will need to provide some further information. Like how do you check for a day? How is a day stored in your database? In which table?

Comment: @LajosArpad : Query and output is provided above, i just need to pick one record per day using same query and its corresponding jobname , stepname & runstatus.

Comment: @Debasis I have read your question, but you need to provide the data I specifically asked for

Comment: @LajosArpad: I am new into SQL Server , i found out some metadata tables like : sysjobs, sysjobhistory & sysjobsteps and tried to frame query according to my needs. Job "Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2" has 11 steps and job "Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing" has 6 steps. We are only considering final step in query because that is the end of the job. We are not storing job info anywhere and trying to get these details from Metadata tables only. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Debasis yes, this is useful information. Indeed, `sysjobs`, `sysjobhistory` and `sysjobsteps` are the tables that manifest in your question. But in order to write a proper answer to your question I would need to know 1. the structure of these tables (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526982/show-create-table-tablename-in-sql-server) and 2. how are you storing the days, because I will need to group by days in the query and I need to know what format of data I am grouping. Is it a timestamp? Or a date without hours minutes, seconds? Is it a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

I wrap your original query in a cte

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT sj.name JobName
        , ISNULL(sjs.step_name, 'Job Status') StepName
        , dbo.agent_datetime(sjh.run_date, sjh.run_time) RunDateAndTime
        , CASE sjh.run_status
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
          END RunStatus
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON sjh.job_id = sjs.job_id AND sjh.step_id = sjs.step_id  
    WHERE (sj.name = 'Daily Cube Processing - Pt1 - T2' AND sjh.step_id = 11) OR 
    (sj.name = 'Daily Exec Summ-Agent Only Cube Processing' AND sjh.step_id = 6)
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobName, StepName ORDER BY RunDateAndTime) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```